# Give user input for batch file via c# code

Tags: c#, batch-file, command-line

I have a batch file which is asking for some user input text in the middle of that process. I need to run this batch file through c# code. I cannot change the bat file. So the option having command line arguments also is not working for me. Is there any way that i can provide the input when it prompts?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using `Process.Start` to run the batch script. In this case you can easily write to the script's standard input, as if you were typing directly on the commandline:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "script.bat";
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.Start();
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("whatever the parameter is...");
```

If necessary, you can wait for the script to ask for the input by setting:

```
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

and "listening" to its standard output using the `process.StandardOutput.Read();` and similar methods